# Does Lay on Hands against undead require a touch attack?

Tags: undead, touch-attacks, pathfinder-2e, champion

If a champion uses their Lay on Hands ability against an unwilling undead creature, does s/he need to make a touch attack roll or does it automatically cause damage?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Lay on Hands does not require an Attack Roll

The [Lay on Hands](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=395) focus spell has a range of Touch, but does not have the Attack trait. Touch Range states (CRB p. 304)

> You can usually touch the target automatically

Because the spell does not have the Attack trait, it does not specifically require an attack roll, and touch range spells without any additional requirements hit automatically. Lay on Hands does however have a basic Fortitude save when used against undead.

Comment: This could be improved by continuing the quote to better describe how Touch range interacts with spells ("though the spell
might specify that the target can attempt a saving throw
or that you must attempt a spell attack roll.") and point out that the Undead get a basic Fortitude Save (which by the definition of a [basic Save](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=295) reduces the damage)