# If my character has the Familiar Conduit feat, how do I calculate the success or failure of a touch spell that uses the familiar?

Tags: feats, spellcasting, familiars, pathfinder-2e, touch-attacks

The description of the [Familiar Conduit](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1972) feat reads:

> Under your tutelage, your familiar has grown attuned to the hidden
> currents of the world and can serve as a conduit for your magic. If
> the next action you use is to Cast a Spell that has a range, the spell
> uses the familiar as its origin point.

Touch is a range, but familiars do not have the required stats to make an attack. How does one calculate the success or failure?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 6):

### Some Touch spells always 'hit'

The range of [touch](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=287) has been [altered](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154872/does-lay-on-hands-against-undead-require-a-touch-attack) since the rules from Pathfinder 1st edition.

> A spell with a range of touch requires you to physically touch the target. You use your unarmed reach to determine whether you can touch the creature. **You can usually touch the target automatically, though the spell might specify that** the target can attempt a saving throw or that **you must attempt a spell attack roll.** If an ability increases the range of a touch spell, start at 0 feet and increase from there.

So for many touch spells, as long as your Familiar can reach the target ([usually](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=163) being in the same space for [Tiny creatures](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=445)), they are affected by the spell.

### Otherwise, you would use your own statistics

The Familiar Conduit spell *only* alters the origin point for the magic. You are the one performing the spellcasting, so you use your own statistics for all purposes, including spell attack rolls.